# PigLatin.java How to call the method in the main method

Tags: java

> **Problem 1**
>
> Write your code in the file PigLatin.java. Your code should go into a method with the following signature. You may write your own main method to test your code. The graders will ignore your main method:
>
> `public static String translate (String original){}`
>
> "Pig Latin" is a fake language used as a children's game. A word in English is "translated" into Pig Latin using the following rules:
>
> If the English word begins with a consonant, move the consonant to the end of the word and add "ay". The letter Y should be considered a consonant.
>
> If the English word begins with a vowel (A, E, I, O, or U), simply add "way" to the end of the word.
>
> (This is a simplified dialect of Pig Latin, of course.)
>
> Write your method so that it returns the pig latin translated original string. You may assume that the input does not contain digits, punctuation, or spaces. The input may be in any combination of uppercase or lowercase. The case of your output does not matter.

**MY QUESTION:**

I don't know how to call the " public static String translate (String original){} " in the main method please help!!!!

**TYPED CODE:**

```
public class PigLatin {
   public static void main(String[] args){


   }
   public static String translate (String original){
       char firstChar;
           String pig;

           //Take out from the main
           String word = IO.readString();
           word = word.toLowerCase();

           firstChar = word.charAt(0);
           if(firstChar == 'a' || firstChar == 'e' || firstChar == 'i' || firstChar == 'o' ||
                   firstChar == 'u'){
               pig = word + "way";
           }
           else{
               pig = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0) + "ay";
           }
           System.out.println(pig);
           return pig;
   }

}
```

Comment: Put `translate("word");` In your `main` method. Run it and see what happens.

Comment: Why are you passing `original` in the `translate` method, when you are not using it anywhere in the given method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 translate("word");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. If you don't mind can you tell me how can output saying bad input using IO.reportBadInput() in this program. I want to do this because if I type @apple I get the result apple@ay which is wrong. Please help!!

Comment: you  have to check string like this public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
} if it is false then you can show the error